# Powershell: Move all files from folders and subfolders into single folder

Tags: powershell

Trying to index and search for a file within 8K files and 2K folders..

Is there a simple Powershell script that can move all files from folders and/or subfolders into one main folder?

don't need to delete the empty folders but would help.

Comment: Bring all child files into the parent with "one command": 
`Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination ./ ;
Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item;`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The fourth example under `help -Examples Move-Item`[1] is close to what you need. To move all files under the `SOURCE` directory to the `DEST` directory you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path SOURCE -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination DEST
```

If you want to clear out the empty directories afterwards, you can use a similar command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path SOURCE -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item

Comment: What if I only know the `source` name but not the `dest`? `dest` for me would be the parent directory, which has an arbitrary name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Surely you must know the destination directory otherwise the operation won't know where the put the files.

Comment: What if I need to maintain the folder structure? this will copy the files but won't maintain the fulder structure

Comment: @JuanMedina For that case you can just remove the `-Recurse` and `-File` flags.

Comment: It actually fails when trying to move folders, it says Access Denied, even though you're admin

Comment: @JuanMedina That sounds to me like a permissions issue or that the directories are still in use somehow.

Comment: @DonCruickshank Check my answer, that one works without issue maintaining the folder structure

Answer (score 1):

Use `.parent` for the parent dir. It can be used recursively: `.parent.parent`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer led to an error for me because of duplicate files. My code solves this by appending a "_x" to duplicate files.
Also the removal should only work, if there are no files left.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -File
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $dest = Join-Path . $file.Name
  if (Test-Path $dest) {
    $i = 1
    do {
      $newName = "$($file.BaseName)_$i$($file.Extension)"
      $newDest = Join-Path . $newName
      $i++
    } while (Test-Path $newDest)
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newDest
  } else {
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dest
  }
}

Get-ChildItem -Directory | Where-Object {(Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -File).count -eq 0} | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item $_ -Recurse}
```